# How to display post_content from database in different <p> on template page?

Tags: php, database, css, get-posts

I am storing some long unstyled text post_content, where title is XXX. I am selecting this content:

```
<?php global $wpdb;
$findContent = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_content  FROM wp_posts WHERE 
 post_title = 'XXXX'");
echo     $findContent;
?>
```

It is a requirement that f$indContent is not styles into the database, so I need to put it into paragraphs. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply run it through [the_content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter:

```
$filteredContent = apply_filters('the_content', $findContent);
echo $filteredContent;
```

Comment: <?php add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_function_name' ) ?>  I should register the_content before that. But what to put in the function? If I use my var $filteredContent it does not work

Comment: does your query work? you can try to get content by title with get_page_by_title() function:
$page = get_page_by_title('About', OBJECT, 'post');
echo $page->ID

Comment: It works!!! the filter creates paragraphs. Thans!! But again, for example I want part of the text to stay untouched and the rest to be in red containers. How can I do that? I can get who text only once.

Comment: than you have to add css classes from editor as well.
Please accept my answer if you think it is the right one)))